# Messaging from desktop

Tags: sms, mms, google-hangouts, moto-x

Is there something besides Moto Connect and Mighty text that would allow you to SMS/MMS from the desktop.  Mac or PC.  I came from a iOS world where iMessaging worked really well for the desktop.  Hangouts is close, but I message a lot people with iPhones so it just doesn't cover enough people.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, we're not "Software Recommendations" here. But you might want to try [Airdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sand.airdroid). Let's you manage your device from your computer, including SMS and calls.

Comment: I can vouch for [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms&hl=en), but it requires a subscription. DeskSMS offers a Chrome extension and a tablet client as well, in addition to being much faster and reliable than MightyText.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot to me like a sort of push notification system. The way I have implement this into my own foot print is to use growl/libnotify on the desktop and [notify my android](http://notifymyandroid.com/) which allows me to have a central cloud based datastore for my alerts.

There is also the option of just emailing all your devices/contacts instead. One can find a [Email To SMS Email Address List](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/) which lists the domains you would need to send a message to for your SMS/MMS communication to be transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MySMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms&hl=en). This is a really nice tool and allows you to send, reply, and delete messages from your browser.